# How do you increase or decrease the height or width of a vim buffer in a way so that when you hold down the key combo, the size constantly changes?

Tags: vim, buffer

How do you increase or decrease the height or width of a vim buffer in a way so that when you hold down the key combo, the buffer size constantly changes?

I know <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> works but it moves it one unit at a time. I am looking for a way that when you do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> and hold down the <kbd><</kbd> that VIM changes the buffer's width fluidly(constantly) until you let go of the <kbd><</kbd>.

Comment: You could use `.` to repeat the last action.

Comment: @Phoshi: I think that's just for editing actions. In fact, `help .` says "Does not repeat a command-line command."

Comment: @Dennis; Oh, looks like you're right, my apologies!

Comment: or could you CTRL W any_number <

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

```
:nmap ^[> :vertical res +1^M
:nmap ^[< :vertical res -1^M
```

To input the `^[`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>. To input the `^M`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As suggested by Heptite in a comment, you can use key-notation instead of literal characters:

```
:nmap <Esc>> :vertical res +1<Enter>
:nmap <Esc>< :vertical res -1<Enter>
```

Results in the same mapping as the example at the top.

Now you can hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>></kbd> to smoothly increase the width or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd><</kbd> to smoothly increase it. It feels kind of weird using it in the right-hand window to me, because I think that I'm moving the separator left and right, but that's not what's happening.

For changing the size of horizontally split windows:

```
:nmap ^[+ :res +1^M
:nmap ^[- :res -1^M
```

These are the regular plus and minus keys rather than the ones on the keypad. On my US keyboard, in addition to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> for <kbd>+</kbd>, but no <kbd>Shift</kbd> for <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: You may use the string <esc> (with the angle brackets) in place of hard-coding escape characters.

Comment: I tried this, but it only work one time, and then I have to press escape and then it works for one time only.

Comment: @AmitYadav: It works for me. See my answer for a small typo correction and some clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `10 ctrl-w <` or `10 ctrl-w >` to change it by 10 units.